# Is this a semantically correct SQLite search query?

Tags: mysql, database, html, sqlite

EDIT** *Not sure if this additional info will help but tried to keep it simple.*

Data is selected by the user via a html form (up to three options for 'gender', up to six for 'colour' and then a single price range can be selected), this data is then handled in a jquery function to construct the string below and save it in a variable. The variable is then used as the sql query, the query string displayed below is the output of this variable.

I'm debugging in chrome's developer tools, there are no errors showing  **

---

Is there anything wrong with this query string?

```
'SELECT * FROM flipflops WHERE colour="black" OR colour="brown" AND gender="mens" OR gender="womens" AND price<=20'
```

Values are correct in that they match with the db. To be honest it seems to return what ever it likes. I'm hoping that it's immediately obvious to somebody what I've done wrong as I'm a clueless newbie.

Any help would b greatly appreciated! :D

---

EDIT** **above is now replaced with which works perfects when you copy it as it is!**

```
'SELECT * FROM flipflops WHERE colour IN ("white","navy","blue") AND gender IN ("mens","juniors") AND price >= 20 AND price <= 30'
```

**I'm having to use RegExp to create the string in jquery as below** *leaving out pricerange for now* but it returns nothing from db and I'm getting no console errors

```
var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;

var queryValue = regExp.exec("SELECT * FROM flipflops WHERE colour IN /(\'" + colourValues.join("','") + "/')\ AND gender IN /(\'" + genderValues.join("','") + "/')\"");
```

Output to console values are dependent on form value selection (sorry for complicating this, I'm so messy!)

```
    Array[2]
0: "('white','blue/')"
1: "'white','blue/'"
index: 41input: 
"SELECT * FROM flipflops WHERE colour IN /('white','blue/') AND gender IN /('womens','juniors/')""
length: 2
```

Comment: As there are only 2 genders the `AND gender="mens" OR gender="womens"` is redundant.

Comment: @david strachan Will that stop it working?

Comment: @davidstrachan I have added more info

Comment: I have sent an answer for you to see

Answer (score 1):

Are you maybe missing a parentheses?

```
SELECT * FROM flipflops 
WHERE
( 
  colour="black" 
  OR colour="brown"
) 
AND 
(
  gender="mens" 
  OR gender="womens"
)
AND price<=20
```

if that is the case you could write it like this as well:

```
SELECT * FROM flipflops 
WHERE colour IN ("black","brown")
AND gender IN ("mens","womens")
AND price<=20
```

Comment: I have used the same format but without needing the operators and that worked fine. I've added some extra info if that helps

Comment: Got to test this when I got to my computer and it works! Problem s I'm having to use `RegExp.exec` and I'm struggling I think. I've put the code above if you can help

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates a dynamic query using Arions IN() operator example. The query is built depending on what boxes are clicked etc.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Red"><label>Red</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Blue"><label>Blue</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Brown"><label>Brown</label><br/>
<!--input type="checkbox" name="gender[]" value="Any"><label>Any</label><br/-->
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="gender[0]" value="Male"><label>Male</label><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="gender[1]" value="Female"><label>Female</label><br/>
<br>
<input type="text" name="cost" ><label>Cost</label><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
// Set up stub of query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM flipflops ";
//Set initial WHERE clause
$clause ="WHERE ";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
//Color set up IN() operator
if(!empty($_POST['color'])){
    $sql .= $clause." colour IN (";
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
    foreach($_POST['color'] as $color){
    $sql .= $color.",";
    }
    $sql = rtrim($sql, ",");
    $sql .= ")";
    //Set to AND after initial WHERE
    $clause =" AND ";
}
//Gender show only one gender, if 2 genders clicked  all 2 genders are selected
if(!empty($_POST['gender']) && count($_POST['gender']) == 1){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
    foreach($_POST['gender'] as $gender){
        $sql .= $clause. "gender = ".$gender;
    }
    $clause =" AND ";
}
//Cost
if(!empty($_POST['cost'])){
    $sql .= $clause." cost = ". $_POST['cost'];
    }
}
echo $sql;
?>
```

Comment: thanks David but it's all client-side done in jqery using SQLite

Comment: Are you generating the query in javascript & sending it as a POST OR GET?

Comment: Neither, I'm using local storage. SQLite - I've added new code above